# How do I get an element from a nodeList ? How to use byTagname/ByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

It looks like I should be paying attention to nodeType before putting it to use or ill get `Cannot read property '1' of null`. For this reason I have come to rely more on `document.querySelector` vs `getElementbyTagname` / `getElementsByClassName`. How do I get an element and use it from getElementsBy*

right now I use this, it works:

```
var my_el = document.querySelector("some_long_path >div > form > div.field-invalid > textarea");
my_el.value="Hey, I input this into a text area ! :D" ;
```

How do I get an element out of getElementsBy*? :

```
my_el = document.getElementsByName("emailform")[0][1]; //ERROR
```

I need an example of how to go though a node list which is what getElementsBy returns? and get an element to use it.

[Here is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu04i.png)

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("emailform")[0] gets the first element
 document.getElementsByTagName("emailform")[1] gets the second element

Comment: I get undefined. I included a picture of the form.

Comment: please do not link an image of your form but include the code and properly format it aswell, using the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Also learn to use dev tools, have a look at the [javascript tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) under *Useful Tools*

Comment: did you guess that "getElementsByName" is a thing? it is not. don't use name="", use id="" and document.querySelector("#formid")

Answer (score 0):

A NodeList is little more than an array, albeit without some of the conveniences. You still access individual elements using array notation, though the forEach method of arrays is (wasn't, haven't checked in years) not available, so you roll your own.

```js
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}
function allByClass(className,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByClassName(className);}
function allByTag(tagName,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tagName);}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func){for (var i=0, n=nodeList.length; i<n; i++) func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList); }

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
  var liElems = allByTag('li');
  
  liElems[0].innerText += " (1st)";
  liElems[1].innerText += " (2nd)";
  liElems[2].innerText += " (3rd)";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why roll your own when you can `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, function(el, i, nodeList){/** dostuff **/})`

Comment: For the same reason any of us use any particular method until finding a better one. Thanks for a better alternative. :)

Comment: You're welcome, you may `apply`/`call` any `Array` method on a `NodeList`(eg. `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `every`, `some` etc.).